# Is it possible to check all coordinates in Point2D.Double array?

Tags: java, equals

I have x,y coordinates stored in a `Point2D.Double` type.

Code:

```
 private Point2D[] block1 = new Point2D[99]
 block1[0] = new Point2D.Double(12,14);
 block1[1] = new Point2D.Double(15,16);
 block1[2] = new Point2D.Double(20,20)
 //etc all to 99.

 //this can run about 10 times creating 10 different sets of x,y coordinates.
```

**Want to iterate through all the arrays see if a specific coordinate is already there. If it is return true. Not sure on the best way to do it.**

So I know that I will need a for/if loop.

Example: I want to check to see if (15,16) is there:

```
for(Point2D block[] : block1){
     if(block.getX() == 15 && block.getY() == 16){
        System.out.println("This is true");
      }
 }
```

So I want it to search through all the arrays to see if there is a (15,16). I can image this syntax is along the right lines but it is not right.

Answer (score 1):

This approach will gets as close as possible to your desired syntax:

```
Point2D target = new Point2D.Double(15, 16);

for(Point2D block : block1){
     if(target.equals(block)){
        System.out.println("This is true");
      }
 }
```

By the way, you mentioned you want 10 times 10 different sets of coordinates, so you need to change the 99 to 100, otherwise you will crash the array:

```
Point2D[] block1 = new Point2D[100];
```

Comment: Minor suggestion: since you know that target is not null, use it on the left side of the equals test.  Just in case the array contains a null.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there, now just extract that to a method:

```
public boolean containsPoint(Point2D[] points, int x, int y) {
  for(Point2D block : points){
     if(block.getX() == x && block.getY() == y){
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
...

/* calling the method */
if(containsPoint(points, 10, 10)) { // do stuff }
```

Comment: Okay that's great I think this is it. However I get an error on 'points' in the for loop. Saying 'foreach not applicable to type 'java.awt.geom.Point2D'

Comment: @bob9123 I don't have an editor at hand, but see my latest edit. Seems I was missing [] to make the points an array. Now it should be iterable.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in this line:

> for(Point2D block[] : block1){

if 'block1' is an array, while iterating 'block's type should be of the array's type. Namely, just Point2D - rather than Point2D[].

As a first step, try this snippet out:

```
for (Point2D block : block1) {
     if (block.getX() == 15 && block.getY() == 16) {
         System.out.println("Found it");
     }
}
```